# Saving an array to file

Tags: vb.net

I been trying to save an array to file but I can only create the text file but no text shows up in actual file. The loop doesn't work the way I want to. I need to store the Cust array into text file.

```
Dim car(4) As Decimal
Dim Cust(4) As String

'Declare module-level constants.
Const PER_DAY_Integer As Integer = 15
Const PER_MILE_Decimal As Decimal = 0.12D



Private Sub CalcButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CalcButton.Click
    'Calculate the rental charges


    Cust(0) = NameTextBox.Text
    Cust(1) = AddressTextBox.Text
    Cust(2) = CityTextBox.Text
    Cust(3) = ZipTextBox.Text
    Cust(4) = StateTextBox.Text

    Try

        car(0) = Decimal.Parse(BeginTextBox.Text)

        Try
            car(1) = Decimal.Parse(EndTextBox.Text)
            Try

                car(2) = Integer.Parse(DaysTextBox.Text)


                'Calculate the number of miles driven and the charges
                car(3) = car(1) - car(0)
                car(4) = (car(3) * PER_MILE_Decimal + car(2) * PER_DAY_Integer)

                'Display the results
                TotalTextBox.Text = car(4).ToString("C")
                MilesTextBox.Text = car(3).ToString("N1")




            Catch ex As Exception

                MessageBox.Show("Input Error", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                DaysTextBox.Focus()

            End Try
        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show("Input Error", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            EndTextBox.Focus()

        End Try

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show("Input Error", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        BeginTextBox.Focus()

    End Try


End Sub

Private Sub ClearButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ClearButton.Click
    'Clear the form

    AddressTextBox.Clear()
    CityTextBox.Clear()
    StateTextBox.Clear()
    ZipTextBox.Clear()
    BeginTextBox.Clear()
    EndTextBox.Clear()
    DaysTextBox.Clear()
    TotalTextBox.Clear()
    MilesTextBox.Clear()
    With NameTextBox
        .Clear()
        .Focus()
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ExitButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitButton.Click
    'End the program

    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub PrintButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PrintButton.Click
    'Print the form

    PrintForm1.PrintAction = Printing.PrintAction.PrintToPreview
    PrintForm1.Print()
End Sub




Private Sub readBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles readBtn.Click

End Sub

Private Sub WriteBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles WriteBtn.Click

    Dim outFile As IO.StreamWriter
    Dim int As Integer = 0
    Dim count As Integer = 0

    outFile = IO.File.CreateText("Cust.txt")


    Do While int < count
        outFile.WriteLine(Cust(1)(int))
        int += 1
    Loop

    outFile.Close()

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: When you debug this, where specifically does it fail?  What is all that other code doing?  Why on earth do you have all those nested `Try` blocks?

Comment: This was an old project that i did a awhile a back. The blocks are for data validation and it works fine. It does not fail, I just get a blank text file, I need it to save the array information to the text file

Answer (score 2):

You were asked where it failed when you debug and you obviously haven't even bothered to debug or you'd have seen the issue.  Look at this from your code:

```
Dim int As Integer = 0
Dim count As Integer = 0

outFile = IO.File.CreateText("Cust.txt")


Do While int < count
    outFile.WriteLine(Cust(1)(int))
    int += 1
Loop
```

Is `int` ever going to be less than `count`?

You can replace the entire contents of that last event handler with one line:

```
IO.File.WriteAllLines("Cust.txt", Cust)
```

Of course, you should not be using file names alone but rather a file path, but that's another issue.

Comment: `Cust(1)(int)` isn't doing what he thinks it does either, but I gave up on this after the first `Try`.

Comment: I received this project from a professor and we were supposed to store the data into file...

Comment: @DourHighArch, quite so.  Hopefully that becomes a non-issue if `File.WriteAllLines` is used.

Comment: @user2857087, and that's exactly what `File.WriteAllLines` does.  There are usually multiple ways to skin a cat.  `File.WriteAllLines` takes a list of strings or other objects and writes them to a file, one per line.  It's a one-liner that does the work of opening the file, looping through the list, writing each item and then closing the file for you.  You only need to perform each step yourself if you need to do something out of the ordinary somewhere between steps.

Comment: what does this error mean?      "The process cannot access the file 'E:\RentalCar -arrays\RentalCar\bin\Debug\Cust.txt' because it is being used by another process."

Comment: @user2857087, it means that you have opened the file twice.  You did get rid of that call to `CreateText`, right?  I said that that one line replaces ALL the code in that method.

Comment: @ user2857087 if this answer solved the question you should click the green check mark at the upper left.